# Using inline CSS when style not present

Tags: html, css

I have an odd situation which I'm trying to improve. I have HTML content that displays fine on my web page, but not on others. I define a style in my page, which I apply to the `<img>` tag to limit its width, and it works great.

What I would like, though, is to have inline CSS on my `<img>` tag that basically says "hey, if that style I specified doesn't exist, do this instead". Is there any way to do that?

*(for those who are curious, this is for content that can be republished elsewhere, and I have no control over the CSS on the other pages)*

**Update**

Perfect, the `!important` rule was exactly what I needed. Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

css:

```
img {
    border: solid 2px red !important;
}
```

html:

```
<img style="border: solid 2px blue;">
```

the img border color will be red, unless the stylesheet is not present, when it will default to blue.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/GyR6N/

Answer (score 1):

In which case, set the default styles (on your stylesheet) to important, like so:

```css
img {
   border: 3px solid black !important;
}
```

And apply your custom inline styling:

```
<img src="foobar" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
```

Your stylesheet will override it, but since it won't exist on different websites, it would use the inline styling instead (unless of course, that site also happens to have an important rule overriding yours!)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is define the style you want to check in your CSS with an !important tag, then add inline styles on your image tag. If the style is available, the !important tag will override the image inline style.

```
img.red
{
    background:red !important;
}

<img class="" style="background:blue;" src="" alt="" />
<img class="red" style="background:blue;" src="" alt="" />
```

Your page will use the blue background for the image unless the image has a 'red' class.